# Adding Logical Drive in SQL Server 2000 Clustered Environment

Tags: sql-server

I have a Sql Server 2000 Clustered (Active/Passive)Production box, My network guy is adding a new Logical Drive to the box. Also he is going to Add logical drive to cluster admin

My Question is He is going to Reboot the Box.

Do i need to stop the Sql Server services before the reboot? And Do i need to test the failover for it, Since he is adding the logical drive to cluster admin?

Please let me know how the process works when adding new drives to the production box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this is a shared SCSI bus, which will require a server reboot to complete the disk connection. If it's on a shared SCSI bus but already connected, it will still require SQL to be taken down momentarily so that the disk can be added as a dependency.  See the following two articles for more explicit detail:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917693.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;175278&sd=tech